# Delineate data coming in through serial port; parse the bits into types such as int or float

Tags: c++

I am communicating with a device via serial port using the Modbus RTU protocol. The data comes in as 8-bit bytes. After parsing, I end up with 4 bytes that I want to 'join' into a single 32-bit field. 
I have been doing this as follows:

---

```
unsigned char bytes[4];
int field;
field = (0x000000FF & bytes[0]);
field = (field << 8);
field = (field & 0x0000FF00);
field  = (field | bytes[1]);
field  = (field << 8);
field  = (field & 0x00FFFF00);
field  = (field | bytes[2]);
field  = (field << 8);
field  = (field & 0xFFFFFF00);
field  = (field | bytes[3]);
```

However, a colleague told me that this method may have unpredictable results on different systems and that, further, it may not work with float or long types.
Can someone explain to me why this might be? And also, if possible, please help me with how I might accomplish the above task in a manner that will yield consistent results across different systems. Thanks!

Comment: First (and the list will grow) int is not 32 bits (it can be anything)

Comment: Second, you will be totally lost if you do not know the byte order (here you might assume network byte order (big endian))

Comment: Third, A floating point value might not be the floating point value you expect. Besides different sizes there are different representations possible.

Comment: Finally: use ntohs/htons or similar for that task.

Comment: @DieterLücking Actually, the device being communicated with is an FPGA I myself have programmed, so I have full control of both ends of the communication. Also, my code does communicate. However, I failed to take Endianness into account when I did my coding, and I was unaware that there were multiple representations of floating point values. Therefore I have two follow-up questions:
1. Is there a go-to 'best' floating point rep? Or does it depend on my application?  
2. Did I luck out on the Endianness and should I prepare my code to deal with a possible Endian miss-match?

Comment: maybe I should just make that into a seperate question so that you can offically answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all unless the data actually is a signed number, you should be using `unsigned` instead of `int`. I also recommend you use the [fixed-width integer types of `<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) if you have them, to explicitly say you are using 8 or 32 bit unsigned integer types.

As for your problem, it's really much easier than you think it is:

```
uint32_t field = bytes[3] << 24 | bytes[2] << 16 | bytes[1] << 8 | bytes[0];
```

If the byte order is the opposite then reverse the order you use for `bytes`.

---

For reconstructing a `float` variable using the same technique, do as above and then do e.g.

```
float value = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&field);
```

Comment: would this also work with float type? And yes, they are actually signed

Comment: @Numi If the floating point value sent is a single-precision 32-bit type sent byte-wise and in the correct byte-order, then yes you could do it too. You need to do some casting and pointer operations though, to tell the compiler that the result of the bit-wise operations are not really an integer but e.g. a `float`.